# Set Event Value for Cloudtrail - all S3 buckets

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get a cloudtrail for all S3 bucket Data but it keeps throwing an error. The template looks like:

```
DataTrail:
 Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
 Properties:
  CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn: 
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CloudtrailLogGroupARN
  CloudWatchLogsRoleArn: 
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CloudTrailLogsRoleARN
  EnableLogFileValidation: true
  EventSelectors:
    - DataResources:
       - Type: AWS::S3::Object
         Values:
            - 'arn:aws:s3:::*'
    - IncludeManagementEvents: false
    - ReadWriteType: All
  IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: true
  IsLogging: true
  IsMultiRegionTrail: true
  KMSKeyId:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-InvoicegenKey-CMK-Arn
  S3BucketName:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-CloudTrailBucket-Name
```

the AWS Doku says it must be a list of string, so I did:

```
         Values:
        - 'arn:aws:s3:::*'
```

But it keeps failing...

Merci in Advance

A

Comment: Can you try setting value to `arn:aws::s3:::.` (or without this trailing dot)? This is what I found on this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_DataResource.html

Comment: @tyron I have tried this to no avail, not even a fully fledged ARN is is working, very weird...

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was pretty easy; I just created a trail via Console and then used `aws cloudtrail get-event-selectors --trail-name <name>` to get the result. then transferred it to my template like this:

```
DataResources:
    - Type: AWS::S3::Object
      Values:
      - arn:aws:s3
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, pretty close though but correct indent should be

```
cloudtrail:
    Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
    Properties:       
      EnableLogFileValidation: Yes
      EventSelectors: 
        - DataResources:
            - Type: AWS::S3::Object
              Values: 
                - arn:aws:s3:::s3-event-step-bucket/    
          IncludeManagementEvents: Yes
          ReadWriteType: All
      IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: Yes
      IsLogging: Yes
      IsMultiRegionTrail: Yes
      S3BucketName: s3-event-step-bucket-storage       
      TrailName: xyz
```